# Remove leading Characters and starting from Numeric

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to remove leading string part of "**PO Box 323**" Kind of string.
I just need to pick 323 for save.How to do that?

**Note:** After first occurrence of numeric can have characters.That is not a problem.
By using sub string only cannot do this.Any idea ?

**UPDATE :** This is the Final Solution :

```
provider.Address.Street = Regex.Match(update.Address.Street, @"\d+.[a-zA-Z\ \d\#]*").Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
\d+.[a-zA-Z\ \d\#]*
```

[image]

tested with http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Nice Tool.But I need to eligible for "2466 Francisco St #104" kind of string also.I am a blank about regex. So could you make it happen for that kind of string also ?

Comment: @Sampath ok, I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

\d+ is the regex for an integer number.

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, though @Anuj 's \d might be a better match depending on your input.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Get numbers from a string
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="item">input string</param>
  /// <returns>only the number in that string</returns>
    public string ExtractNumbersFromString(string item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            return item;

        return Regex.Replace(item, "[A-Z ]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString();
    }
```